# Find which character is repeated most times in a sentence or a word

Tags: python, string

```
most = 0
list_of_letters = []


def remove(string):
    return "".join(string.split())


sentence = input('Enter a sentence or a word: ')


new = remove(sentence)
new = new.lower()


for i in new:
    rep = 0
    for n in new:
        if i == n:
            rep += 1                              ###hhello
    if rep > most:
        list_of_letters = [i]
        most = rep
    elif rep == most:
        for z in list_of_letters:
                    if i == z:
                        break
                    else:
                        list_of_letters.append(i)   

print(list_of_letters)


for index in list_of_letters:
    print(index, end=(" "))
print(f'is repeated the most at {most}')
```

The problem comes when a character of the same amount of repetitions is tried to append in the array of `list_of_letters`. It should not get appended in array if its already in the array but it does a lot of times.

Comment: Two easy solutions: check if `i not in list_of_letters`, or even better, use a set.

Comment: You should follow that excellent piece of advice, but note that your current code would work if you match the `else` with `for`, not `if`.

Comment: each iteration of `i` has an opportunity to set `most` for that `i` character. Therefore your `list_of_letters` is reset to just that character and the next time that same letter comes up it may or may not trigger based on the last letter's `most` calculation. All in all, this is WAY over engineered for something that could just be `set(new)`.

Comment: Or in a more iterative fashion like you were doing: `list_of_letters = [x for i, x in enumerate(new) if x not in list(new)[:i]]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the letters. Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to select only the letters from the lowercased sentence. Note that `most_common(1)` returns only 1 most commonly occurring character in the order of appearance. So in the example below, it prints `o` but not `b`. But if you want *all* most commonly occurring letters, it is trivial to access the `Counter` elements.

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = input('Enter a sentence or a word: ')
letters = [c for c in sentence.lower() if c.isalpha()]
cnt = Counter(letters)
print(f"letters: occurrences: {cnt}")
print(f"most common: {cnt.most_common(1)}")
```

**Example:**

Input:

```
Enter a sentence or a word: foo bbar.
```

Output:

```
letters: occurrences: Counter({'o': 2, 'b': 2, 'f': 1, 'a': 1, 'r': 1})
most common: [('o', 2)]
```

Comment: Something like `mc = cnt.most_common(1); print(f'most common: {[p for p in cnt.items() if p[1] == mc[0][1]]}')` will show all of the letters tied for most common.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at ways to help fix your current code, I would look at using `in` to help accumulate a list of distinct letters as well as avoid work we already did.

```py
    if i in list_of_letters:
        continue
    else:
        list_of_letters.append(i)
```

That will allow us to also get rid of a big block of code at the end of your for loop.

**Full Example:**

```py
def remove(string):
    return "".join(string.split())

sentence = input('Enter a sentence or a word: ')
new = remove(sentence)
new = new.lower()

list_of_letters = []
most_letter = ""
most = 0

for i in new:
    ## ---------------
    ## if we already counted this letter we can skip doing so again
    ## ---------------
    if i in list_of_letters:
        continue
    ## ---------------

    ## ---------------
    ## ---------------
    ## If we get here, this is a new letter we have not seen before
    ## ---------------
    ## ---------------

    list_of_letters.append(i)

    ## ---------------
    ## Count how many times letter "i" appears in "new"
    ## ---------------
    rep = 0
    for n in new:
        if i == n:
            rep += 1
    ## ---------------

    ## ---------------
    ## If the prior count "rep" is more than are current max
    ## ---------------
    if rep > most:
        most_letter = i
        most = rep
    ## ---------------

    ## ---------------
    ## This count is less than some prior count
    ## we can ignore it
    ## ---------------
    #elif rep == most:
    #    for z in list_of_letters:
    #                if i == z:
    #                    break
    #                else:
    #                    list_of_letters.append(i)   
    ## ---------------

print(f"In the phrase '{sentence}'")
print(f"The most common letter was: '{most_letter}' found {most} times")
print(f"Distinct Letters: '{''.join(list_of_letters)}'")
```

If you run that and enter "hello world" when prompted you will get back:

```
In the phrase 'hello world'
The most common letter was: 'l' found 3 times
Distinct Letters: 'helowrd'
```

**Alternate Approach:**

There are a numbers of easy improvements you might also look at. For example, a call to `list_of_letters = list(set(new))` will give you your distinct letters and `rep = new.count(i)` will count up the number of times the letter `i` appears in `new`.

However, to get the distinct list of letters and their counts at the same time we can leverage `collections.Counter`. It will do more or less all the work for us.

```py
import collections

sentence = input('Enter a sentence or a word: ')

## -----------
## make someone else do the work for us
## -----------
counted_letters = collections.Counter(sentence.lower().replace(" ", ""))
## -----------

list_of_letters = list(counted_letters.keys())
most_letter, most = counted_letters.most_common(1)[0]

print(f"In the phrase '{sentence}'")
print(f"The most common letter was: '{most_letter}' found {most} times")
print(f"Distinct Letters: '{''.join(list_of_letters)}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dictionary to count occurrences python has built in things to make this simple:

```py
sentence = input("enter a sentence or a word: ")
max = None
max_count = 0

letters = dict()

for letter in sentence:
    if not letter.isalpha():
        continue
    my_letter = letter.lower()
    count = 1
    if my_letter not in letters:
        letters[my_letter] = 1
        # count is already set to 1
    else:
        count = letters[my_letter] + 1
        letters[my_letter] = count
    if count > max_count:
        max_count = count
        max = my_letter

print(f'{max} is repeated the most at {max_count}')
```

Comment: your `count` variable is not doing anything useful. Why not just `letters[my_letter] = letters[my_letter] + 1` or, even better, `letters[my_letter] += 1` ?  You could also use a `defaultdict` with a default value of 0 and not need the `not in` check.

Comment: `count` variable is used to avoid extra lookback to track the `max_count` so i dont have to do another `n` iteration over the dictionary at the end to find the max count letter.

Comment: by the time you get to the comparison with `max_count`, the value you want to compare it with is in `letters[my_letter]` either way.  You don't need a separate variable to hold it.

Comment: yes i could use a defaultdict but i was trying to keep it as simple as possible for the beginner.  your other suggestions are syntactic sugar. `+= 1` is not any different from what I have written.  You are arguing points that make no difference in the code execution at all.

Comment: I'm not sure pointing out the complexity of their current solution is all that helpful. I'm sure they would have written a simpler solution if they knew how. I would highlight that python often has simple/clean alternatives for many common tasks.